# How can I use "find" in shell scripts to search from current directory and most importantly subdirectories?

Tags: bash, scripts

My script does work, but the script only searches its current directory. I would like my script to search for a file in the subdirectories. This is what I have so far.

```
#!/bin/bash
read -p "file name:" fname
if find . -name "$fname"
        then
        cat -n $fname
else
        echo "file not found, try again. But, this time focus please!"
fi
```

Comment: As it stands, `find` is searching in the subdirs..possible X-Y question..

Comment: Yes, that is correct. But, it doesn't display the file contents on the screen!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your script can be simplified. `find` command itself has `-exec`  flag, which allows executing commands to operate on the files found.

Also, if you want to find a specific file , you don't need a script. Here's an example:

```
$ cat testdir/file2.txt                                                        
HelloAskubuntu
$ find  -name "file2.txt" -exec cat {} \; 2> /dev/null                         
HelloAskubuntu
```

As  you can see, this finds specific file `file2.txt` in subdirectory of my current working directory, and `cat`s it.

If you want to find a set of files with something in filename, you could either use `-regex` flag or simply wildcard.

```
$ find  -name "file*.txt" -printf "%P:\n"  -exec cat {} \; 2> /dev/null        
file1.txt:
HelloAskubuntu
testdir/file2.txt:
HelloAskubuntu
```

Note the usage of `-printf` flag to print path to file found first, and then catinate it.

Refer to `find`'s manual page for more info on it's flags and options

Also, in and of itself, your script is incorrect: you're basically doing the test `if command find successfully exits, catinate "$fname"` . You are not telling `find` to do anything about the files found and you're not passing its output to any further commands to operate on.

If you insist on using read+find, I'd still advise you to use `-exec` flag, or at least pass the output on to a while loop

```
$ cat testscript.sh                                                            
#!/bin/bash

read -p"Enter filename:" FILE
find -name "$FILE" -exec cat {} \; 2> /dev/null
$ ./testscript.sh
Enter filename:file2.txt
HelloAskubuntu
$
```

Here's another way:

```
$ ./testscript.sh                                                              
Enter filename:file2.txt
./testdir/file2.txt
HelloAskubuntu
$ cat testscript.sh
#!/bin/bash

read -p"Enter filename:" USERINPUT

find -name "$USERINPUT" -print0  2>/dev/null  | while IFS="" read -r -d "" FILE;
do
  echo "$FILE"
  cat "$FILE"
done
$
```

The method above is more general way of dealing with filenames, aimed especially to [avoid issues with files that contain special characters in their name](http://www.dwheeler.com/essays/filenames-in-shell.html) However, for the 90% of what you're doing here, the `-exec` flag approach I showed is sufficient

Comment: Thank you Serg. It worked!! I would like to thank everyone for taking the time to assist me in writing correct shell scripts.

Answer (score 0):

By default, `find` does search subdirectories so you're headed in the right direction.

Your `if` uses the return code from `find` to decide if it found anything or not but that's not what `find`'s return code means. `find` returns true if there were no errors encountered while searching for files.

If you want to check whether `find` actually found files, check that it printed something to stdout:

```
find_stdout=`find . -name "$fname"`
if [ "$find_stdout" != "" ]; then
    # Found file(s) case
else
    # Found nothing case
fi
```

Comment: Thank you caffeine.storm! Do you know if find_stdout is able to locate if a process is actually running in the background. For instance I'm running an infinite loop and my script will kill the process and display message "Process filename not running". Do you think is a good idea to use find_stdout to check if a process is running?

Comment: @ep7network 'find_stdout' was just a local variable that held a string containing all of the output from 'find'. 'find' only reports filenames to stdout so I don't think this would be useful for determining whether a process is running or not.

Checkout 'pgrep' for your case.

Comment: You are correct. I used 'pgrep' and my script is working. Thank you for your time.